# Merging two output dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For my first dataframe I predicted the `Decision` using XGBoost:

```
    itemId     property_1      property_2     property_n       Decision
 0      i1          88.90             NaN              0           Good
 1      i2          87.09    7.653800e+06              0            Bad
 2      i3          78.90    7.623800e+06              1           Good
 3      i4          93.02             NaN              1            Bad
 ...


import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas as pd

cols_to_drop = ['itemId'] # drop the non-feature columns
df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)

X = df.drop('Decision', axis=1)  # feature columns
y = df['Decision'] # variable that we need to predict

model = XGBClassifier() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
model = XGBClassifier() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

For the second one I predicted, again, the `Decision` (note that there might be items here that didn't appear in the first dataframe):

```
     userId        itemId      Decision
  0      u1            i1             0
  1      u1            i2             1
  2      u2            i1             1
  3      u2            i3             0
  4      u2            i4             1
  5      u3            i5             0
    ...

import numpy as np
from surprise import KNNWithMeans, Dataset, Reader
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

reader = Reader(rating_scale=(0, 1))
data = Dataset.load_from_df(df_2[['userId', 'itenId', 'Decision']], reader)
trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.25)
algo = KNNWithMeans()
algo.fit(trainset)
test = algo.test(testset)
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
test.drop("details", inplace=True, axis=1)
test.columns = ['userId', 'itemId', 'actual', 'cf_predictions']
```

Since the output of the second code block gives me something like (for the test set!):

```
     userId        itemId       actual      cf_predictions
  0      u3            i5            0                0.05
  1      u3            i6            1                0.66
  2      u4            i1            1                0.99
  3      u4            i3            0                0.04
  4      u5            i4            1                0.98
  5      u5            i5            0                0.06
  ...
```

I would like to add the predictions from the first algorithm to the above dataframe. So an extra column with the `y_pred` for each item. The problems:

1. `y_pred` can be converted to 0's and 1's, so that is easy.
2. I have to somehow add `y_pred` to the `X_test` set so that I see for each item the result is?
3. The test sets probably don't match much, so when merging the two dataframes I would barely get anything.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Have a look at the *outer* join. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html
Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could use `itemId` as the key to join your last dataframe with the `Decision` column from your first dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'itemId': ['i0', 'i1', 'i2', 'i3'],
                   'property_1': [88.90, 87.09, 78.90, 93.02],
                   'Decision': ['Good', 'Bad', 'Good', 'Bad']})

test = pd.DataFrame({'userId': ['u3', 'u3', 'u4', 'u4', 'u5', 'u5'],
                     'itemId': ['i5', 'i6', 'i1', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5'],
                     'actual': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                     'cf_predictions': [0.05, 0.66, 0.99, 0.04, 0.98, 0.06]})

predicted = df[['itemId', 'Decision']].set_index('itemId')

test.join(predicted, on='itemId')
```

```
    userId  itemId  actual  cf_predictions  Decision
0   u3      i5      0       0.05            NaN
1   u3      i6      1       0.66            NaN
2   u4      i1      1       0.99            Bad
3   u4      i3      0       0.04            Bad
4   u5      i4      1       0.98            NaN
5   u5      i5      0       0.06            NaN
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why I need to transform the itemId's. I just want to add `y_pred` to the corresponding `itemId` from `X_test` (although the column `itemId` is no longer there, I only have the random remaining indices that were selected for the test), and then merge this to that last dataframe that I wrote there. If there are any matches, that's good, if not, we leave it to NaN, for example.

Comment: You are right, you can also keep them as strings. For some reason I had thought the `itemId`s in the first dataframe were integer values, but now I see that wasn't the case. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I upvoted and accepted. Right now I was playing around with the models and simply decided to just apply them on the whole dataset, not just on the test set. It would make things easier and avoid so many NaNs. For the first one it's easy, but for the second one I can't figure out how to apply it to the whole thing since `trainset` has the strange format `<surprise.trainset.Trainset at 0x168b344ad90>`.